# Html/Css Issue anchor tag

Tags: html, css

This is my site http://igbowomenassembly.org/, I am using a theme, when I click on Our Executive-> National Executive, A sub-menu appears but I am not able to click to all the items, when I try to click to vice-president it automatically shows me the Engugu Executive menu.

Thank you all for helping me and sorting my issue.

Sorry all but i am not familier with Html/css alot, the issue is on all browsers.

/*** Main Menu 
/////////////////////////////// ***/

```
    .menu-bar {
    background:#222222;
    }
.menu-bar .menu {
    display:inline-block;
}
.menu {
    list-style:none;
}
.menu li {
    position:relative;
}
.menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
}
.menu > li > a {
    padding:15px 22px;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
}
.menu li:hover > a {
    background:#000;
}

.menu-bar li ul {
    width:172px;
    height:0px;
    padding:0;
    background:#000;
    z-index:201;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    opacity:0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:50px;

    border-radius:0px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 3px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 3px 3px 3px;

    transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;
}
.menu li li a {
    padding:10px 12px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;

    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}

.menu-bar li li {
    display:none
}
.menu-bar li:hover li {
    display:block
}
.menu-bar li li a {
    display:block;
}
.menu-bar li li:hover > a {
    background:#222;
}
.menu-bar li:hover > ul {
    overflow:visible;
    padding:8px;
}
.menu-bar li:hover > ul {
    height:auto;
    opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
.menu-bar li > ul ul {
    height:auto;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-top:-8px;
    left:100%;
    top:0px;
}
.menu-bar li li:hover > ul {
    opacity:1;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Please, post your html, css and other infos that could help us to help you.

Comment: Also, doing what you said you couldn't do worked for me in Win/Chrome, so you need to be a bit more specific about where it doesn't work. You should try to do some bug testing yourself: try it in several different browsers, then tell us which browser(s) it doesn't work in.

Comment: @Setek i am a new user, i have tried my best to explain my quesiton please promote me so that i can use stackoverflow in future.

Comment: We were all new users at some point. If somebody tells you that your question isn't clear or you need to provide more information, they're probably right.

Comment: @kehrk i have explained my issue..

Comment: Check out @LeonardoR.'s comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple `z-index` issue. The line at:

```
.menu-bar li ul
```

Is telling all submenus to have a `z-index` of 201. If all submenus, hidden at the time or not, have the same `z-index`, then the one that comes lower down in source order will supercede the one above it. This is why the lower down menu suddenly pops.

If you update only the hovered submenu to have a higher index, then it will supercede any submenus lower down in the source order. So by updating this code:

```
.menu-bar li li:hover > ul {
    opacity:1;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 202; /* this is a new line */
}
```

Will fix your issue.

Here is a jsFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/2WcBW/